# STM32 through SWD gives error with increasing HCLK (Break at address)

Tags: stm32, clock, swd

I have custom board which I program through SWD pins.
When I debug with 16Mhz(default clock), my blink code works.
When I increase it with PLLCLK, it gives an error such as "Break at address "0x2b003300" with no debug information available, or outside of program code." with different addresses.

PLLCLK 16Mhz works.
RCC HSE Crystal/Ceramic Resonator
SYS Trace Asynchronous Sw/Serial Wire (tried both)

In debugger screen, SWD is selected and enabled. I tried with various SWV Clock.

Comment: 16MHz as the crystal frequency? Are you saying with HSI, it works, but not with HSE?

Comment: crystal frequency is 25Mhz. HSI is 16Mhz. No matter System Clock Mux is selected, it works if HCLK is 16Mhz or lower.